# Transfer BT Low Energy GATT profiles via EDR between two dual mode devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

When two dual mode Bluetooth devices are connected, they must use EDR and cannot use LE in parallel. The BT Low Energy GATT profiles must then be transfered over the EDR link. This is what I read from the specs.

But does the iOS EDR Stack (that has heavy restrictions without MFi license) then also accept the Low Energy GATT profiles?

Thanks!

Comment: I read it as you have the choice to use EDR or LE-GATT, but not both.  I know nothing about iOS, though.

Comment: @Bernd : Can you point me in which spec u have checked(i am curious to know , don't take it otherwise) ,i think that LE and EDR are 2 separate BT standards.

Comment: @ashish: I've found this in: BT LE 4.0 Volume 3; Part C (Generic Access Profile). It is also confirmed in the documents of the CSR chips. It looks like this limitation will be removed in BT LE 4.1. But of course it will be questionalbe whether Apple will support 4.1.

Comment: @Bernd : Thx for info. even  i too dig the same, if two deviecs are dual mode, then you cannot setup le conn, you can set up bredr acl connection, and do gatt over bredr however none of the profiles support gatt over bredr( per my knowledge) ,

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the BT 4.0 spec does not allow 2 devices to be connected using LE + BR/EDR at the same time. The BT 4.1 spec seems to have loosened this requirement.

However, in practice, iOS *does* allow a LE+BR/EDR accessory to connect using either (and both at the same time as well!) In fact, iOS does not even support GATT over BR/EDR (source: an Apple engineer told me in person).

Note that this means users need to pair twice, assuming the application requires encryption for the LE link. BT 4.2 added "Cross Transport Key Generation" which should resolve this issue. Supposedly iOS 8.2 supports BT 4.2, but I have not tried this feature yet.